# $compile is loading images before the string is even evaluated for Angular expressions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am building a service to handle modal windows in my Angular application, so there is a bit of manual work with linking a template, scope and controller.

I'm using $compile like so, to build the template and attach to the scope, for example:

```
$compile('<h1>This is my window</h1><img src="{{ imageUrl }}">')($scope);
```

Everything is working fine, but... the browser tries to load anything such as an image before the HTML string has even been evaluated for Angular expressions. For example, in this case, the browser tries to literally load "http://myhost.com/{{ imageUrl }}", and then immediately afterwards will load the correct URL as the Angular expression is picked up.

This happens immediately upon the $compile()($scope) is called, without even attaching/inserting the returned template to the DOM.

Basically the browser seems to be parsing the HTML before Angular replaces the Angular expressions - any kind of remote content in the HTML at all will be requested by the browser. How is this so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [ng-src](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc) instead of src. That's what it's for.

Comment: Such a simple solution, thanks so much. I'll mark your answer as the accepted one as soon as I can, since you were first to answer by 20-30 seconds! Is this a normal thing for Angular then, even when using Angular's own routing/template options? I genuinely couldn't find an answer to my problem via Google but perhaps I was searching the wrong words.

Comment: I can't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: Usually with Angular you may use something like use ngRoute, ngInclude or set templateUrl configuration on a directive. E.g. not normally running $compile yourself. I was just wondering if the same requirement of using ng-src over src would apply when using those built-in options. I could just check this myself though so nevermind, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ng-src in the img tag.